# Delete first list element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following list:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>    
</ul>
```

How can I use jQuery to remove the first element of this list (i.e. the number 1) and leave the remaining elements intact?

I'd have thought this have quite a simple solution but it's proving harder than I expected to answer.

Comment: I tried searching SO for an answer, didn't find anything, so thought it could do with this not uncommon question being asked.

Comment: I find Google searches tend to produce better results than SO searches (noting that Google searches on this type of issue often produce results from SO).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$('#list li').first().remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DvGa9/)**

Ref:

- [first](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
- [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

You could also accomplish a similar effect using pure CSS3 (no JavaScript) with:

```
#list li:nth-child(1) {
    display:none;
}​
```

Comment: or `$('#list li').eq(0).remove();`

Comment: @Peter - yup. six of one, half dozen of another. Several ways to skin a cat with jQuery.

Comment: @Peter isn't `.first()` alias for `.eq(0)`? `first()` is more readable and does absolutely the same thing, why would you change this?

Comment: yes, but I prefer to use `eq()`. This way you can select any element by it's index number or using a variable or a function result. But in this particular case, it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#list li:first-of-type").remove();
```

Comment: Does jQuery make `:first-of-type` compatible with older browsers (e.g., IE8)? It's not mentioned on the jQuery site (that I can find).

Comment: Hmmm, just tried it. It seems it's not supported on IE8 and lower. Didn't see that coming, my bad.