# jQuery remove first class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some problems with removing class with jQuery.

As you know when i open modal in bootstrap it appears code like

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in">
```

in footer. But when i open modal in modal (2 modals) there is 2 div with same code and i have to remove one.
I have developed a function that is actually work, but i have to remove only 1 div with same class.

This is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    });
});
```

So how i can delete only one div with that function, is it possible?

Comment: you can use `eq()`: https://api.jquery.com/eq/
for example: `$(".modal-backdrop").eq(0).remove()`

Comment: something like this: `$(".close").click(function(){
        $(this).parent('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete first list element using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232431/delete-first-list-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,
i have code now that is working like expected.

```
 $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".second-modal").attr("hidden", "");
        $(".modal-backdrop").first().remove();
    });
```